# Why do I have to pass the letter 'e' into this jQuery function?

Tags: jquery

I know that E is short for 'event,' but it's still not clear to me why I need to use it? I tried passing other letters through the function and it didn't seem to work. Are there other situations where I need to pass a specific letter into a function?

```
$("#myThing").click(function (e) {
   var hit = $(e.target);
   hit.css('color','blue');
});
```

This does the same thing:

```
$("#myThing").click(function () {
   $(this).css('color','blue');
});
```

When should I use $(this) versus 'e'?

Thank you!

Comment: *"I tried passing other letters through the function and it didn't seem to work"* - Then you did something else wrong, it will work fine.

Comment: Variables (and by extension, parameters) are such a fundamental part of programming that you should stop whatever it is you're trying to do with jQuery, and learn the basics of JavaScript programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to pass a specific letter through the function.

```
$("#myThing").click(function (e) {
   var hit = $(e.target);
   hit.css('color','blue');
});
```

is identical to

```
$("#myThing").click(function (foo) {
   var hit = $(foo.target);
   hit.css('color','blue');
});
```

etc.

The difference between using `$(e.target)` and `$(this)` can be quite more significant though, since `this` will always be the element on which the event is tied, while `e.target` will be the specific element that was clicked, even though it's located inside the `this` element

Hope that made sense

Answer (score 2):

The name `e` is meaningless;  you can call it whatever you want (obviously so long as you update the references to `e` as well).

The code you posted will *usually* do the same thing; but see the following code:

```html
​<div><span>Hi</span></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

JS:

```
​$('div').on('click', function (e) {
    alert(this === e.target);
});​​​​​
```

(Run in here: http://jsfiddle.net/Dxbwm/)

You'll see it's false; thats because `this` is the element the event is handled on, but `e.target` is the element the event originated from (which in the example above, is the span). If you didn't know events worked like this before, it's called *event bubbling* and you can read more about it [here](http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2012/05/what-does-event-bubbling-mean/)<sup>my blog</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

Events can carry data with them (eg a Dropped file). If you need to refer to the data that belongs to the event, use "e". If you only need to refer to the element that the event was triggered from - which is what 'this' refers to in an event callback - use 'this'.

Answer (score 1):

there's a small difference between the two snippets: in the first one, the element `hit` could not be the `#myThing` element itself.

Let say that `#myThing` is a `<p>` and you have clicked on a link *inside* it: then when the event will reach `#myThing`, the element referred by `e.target` is the link and not the paragraph

On the contrary, in the second example the element subject to a color change will always be `#myThing`

So, if you pass the event along with the handler it's because you have a convenience on using that event. When you pass it, you can name it `e` or `evt` or also `foobar`: since you're using jQuery the variable name you choose is not relevant (but for the sake of simplicity `e` is short and widely used).

The most common reasons to pass the event usually are

1. prevent the default behavior of the event;
2. stop the propagation of the event;
3. — it's your scenario — deal with the original element in which the event was triggered (often when you're dealing with event delegation or with live update of your document);
4. check some of the event properties (e.g. `e.keycode` on `keyup/down` event);

Answer (score 1):

See, in this case `event.target` and `this` are referring to the same element. But when you use jQuery [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/), they may not match:

```
$('body').on('click', 'tr', function(event) { ... });
```

Here `event.target` will refer to the element at which the event was triggered (it may be 'td' element or its children, for example), but `this` will refer to the `tr` element. Sometimes it's quite handy to have both of them. )

Besides, yes, event object has some other uses: with it you can stop propagation of the event, etc.